# /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lc

Tags: linux, make

```
[root@localhost chkrootkit-0.49]# make sense
gcc -DHAVE_LASTLOG_H -o chklastlog chklastlog.c
gcc -DHAVE_LASTLOG_H -o chkwtmp chkwtmp.c
chkwtmp.c: In function âmainâ:
chkwtmp.c:95: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function âexitâ
gcc -DHAVE_LASTLOG_H   -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -o ifpromisc ifpromisc.c
gcc  -o chkproc chkproc.c
gcc  -o chkdirs chkdirs.c
gcc  -o check_wtmpx check_wtmpx.c
gcc -static  -o strings-static strings.c
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lc
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [strings-static] Error 1
```

What does that mean? Do I need to yum install something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following

```
 yum install glibc-static
```